# Not able to switch java home properly in mac

Tags: java, macos, version

I have two versions of Java in my mac and I am trying to switch from 1.8 to 1.7 for compiling one of my project which has 1.7 specific contents. Though I ran the following commands in the terminal:

```
$ alias setJdk1.7='export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)'
$ setJdk1.7
```

With that, I can see the proper version in java -version and mvn -version.

```
$ java -version

java version "1.7.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_181-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.181-b09, mixed mode)

$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (...)
Maven home: *mvn path*
Java version: 1.7.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

However, the /usr/libexec/java_home still seems to be pointing to the 1.8 java only.

```
$ echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I am very new to mac and not really sure how I can toggle between versions. This is not allowing to successfully compile my project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a function instead and setting up your command as follows:

```
setJdk1.7() {
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
}
```

Your command likely doesn't work because `$JAVA_HOME` is never added to your `$PATH`.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, how do I execute a function? Should it be in a .bash? Anyways, I tried to run these two commands separately, the echo $JAVA_HOME gives the 1.7 version however the echo of /usr/libexec/java_home still shows 1.8

Comment: To execute a function it's much like an alias, so you'd just do `setJdk1.7` from the Terminal prompt. Can you please post the output of the command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`.

Comment: $ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_151, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_181, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: @SRS: Things seem in the correct place; are you always in the same terminal window while changing/checking versions? Also does `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0)` make any difference (notice the zero on the end)?